# Cannot delete a file from Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I've been working on a Blazor project with Visual Studio 2019 but when I need to delete a file from solution explorer, there is no any option about deleting/remove. What is the reason of that and how can I solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this always the case (debugging, no debugging, after restart, etc.)? I think in some situations (e.g. during debugging) the solution explorer is set to readonly.

Comment: Yes, this is always like that, it is not in debugging for this case.

Comment: And just pressing the delete key doesn't do anything either I assume?

Comment: Can you not just "Open Containing Folder" and delete manually as a last resort?

Comment: Are you using source control?  Look at the icons in front of the items...

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows that you are actively debugging at the moment. @Joelius already said that in this case the files in the solution explorer cannot be deleted. Stop debugging by pressing the red square in the top bar of VS and you are able to delete them.